# How to use $display without initial or always blocks

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to debug a Verilog module that doesn't use initial or always by using $display statements. However, these appear to be illegal outside of initial or always blocks. Why is that? What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? Because that's how the IEEE standard has specified it.

An alternative is to scope down into your module instance from your testbench.  Your testbench will have an `initial` or `always` block which will call `$display`.  Another useful system task is `$monitor`:

```
module tb;

reg a = 0;

dut dut ( .a(a) );

initial begin
    $monitor("time=%0t, a=%b, b=%b", $time, a, dut.b);
    #5 a = 1;
    #5 a = 0;
    #5 $finish;
end

endmodule

module dut (input a);
    wire b = ~a;
endmodule
```

You should get this kind of output when you run a simulation:

```
time=0, a=0, b=1
time=5, a=1, b=0
time=10, a=0, b=1
```

The `dut.b` signal is a hierarchical specifier that allows you to scope down into another module from the top-level module (`tb`).  `dut` is the instance name, and `b` is the signal name inside the dut instance.  A period separates the instance name from the signal name.